# Tweet Button ; not allow users to edit content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter

With "**Tweet Button**" user goes through the below steps:

1. The user clicks the Tweet Button
2. The user is asked to login to Twitter if they aren't already. If the user is new to Twitter they can also create an account.
3. The Share Box appears already completed with the information provided in the properties of the Tweet Button. The user can change the content if they wish.
4. Posting of the Tweet is confirmed and the user is suggested a maximum of two accounts they may wish to follow as provided in the properties of the Tweet Button.
5. The Share Box remains open until the user presses close.

Below is the code when add Tweet Button:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s) [0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

My question is:

Regarding step 3, how should we write the code to stop users from editing the content ? 
I am really appreciated your helps.

Comment: you cant force the users to say what you want them to

Comment: I do not force but I want to protect my content and the original meaning of it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible as if it was so, users won't have control over their tweets..